# How to mock method of each instance of class

Tags: java, android

I have method which use method of other object `new MyClass()`. I test mentioned class in isolation (other test). But is possible mock method of each instance required class in test? I need to behaviour method of MyClass.

Tested class:

```
public class A {

  public String methodA(int a, int b){
    MyClass object = new MyClass(a, b);
    String a = object.method();
    // complex computation
    return "result";
  }
}
```

Something like this:

```
when(new MyClass.method()).thanReturn("abcd")
```

Comment: You should include more details. It is unclear to me if you know what mocking is, what you have tried to do so etc. It is also unclear if you are using a framework or library to mock.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to replace the functionality of a method in a class,
during unit testing,
you create a wrapper for the class and replace the method in the wrapper.

If you are using `Mockito`,
you create the wrapper for the class by creating a `Spy` on the class.
Once you have a spy,
you can use the behavior functionality of Mockito (when ... thenReturn) to replace the method.

Here is a simple example:

```
@Spy
private MyClass classToTest;

@Before
public void preTestSetup()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    doReturn("blammy").when(classToTest).getHooty();
}

@Test
public void someTest()
{
    // This prints "blammy".
    System.out.println(classToTest.getHooty());
}
```

**Edit**
Now that the question has changed,
the answer needs to change as well.

As mentioned in the @GhostCat answer,
you can't change the return value of new with `Mockito`.
I would not do that.
Instead,
in a situation like yours,
I would create a `MyClassFactory` (or builder, whatever)
that creates instances of `MyClass`.
I would add a `MyClassFactory` instance to class `A`.
Then I would inject a `MyClassFactory` that returns a mock instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: You show classic example. It is clear. I need to mock of behavior of method class MyClass. New object is created when method is called.

Comment: I think you should remove that part about the spy. It really doesnt apply here, and is actually pretty misleading to unexperienced readers.

Comment: The part about spy is the answer to the original question.  The post edit part is the answer to the changed question.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the "direct" answer would be to use a framework such as PowerMock or JMockit. These allow you to "intercept" calls to new() to then return a mock. Mockito can't do that.

But the preferred way would be to not call new directly in your production code. Instead you look into dependency injection mechanisms. In other words: instead of changing the mocking framework you change your production to be easier to test.

Adding some more details, to show how **necessary** my answer is.

```
when(new MyClass.method()).thanReturn("abcd")
```

What you don't understand is that `when()` works on **mocked** objects. You are under the wrong assumption that `when()` can magically know whenever `method()` is invoked on **any** MyClass object. But that is wrong. `when()` only knows that when you `when(someMockedMyClassInstance)` ... that it has to "monitor" the calls going to that one specific `someMockedInstanceObject`.

Beyond that, `new()` isn't a normal method. You can't simply mock it. As said, you are left with **two** choices:

- you use [PowerMock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor) to intercept the call to new. And right there, you provide a mocked instance (instead of new() creating a real new object. And as you now have a mocked object, you can control the behavior of that object
- you get rid of that call to `new()` in your production code, by using **alternative** ways to provide the required object to the production code. See [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mockito_dependencyinjection) for *one* way how to use @InjectMocks to do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Mock
MyClass myClass;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void myClassTest() {
    when(myClass.classMethod()).thanReturn("abc")
}
```

If you are using Mockito, try this!